# Code works on JS Fiddle but not in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

This is supposed to be a guided help program for people filling out a paper application.  At this stage it is just a proof of concept to be completed with way more detail later.  As people answer questions, they are presented with another question depending on their answer, and eventually will be given instructions on that part of the application.  I wanted to test someone just answering yes over and over.  It works in JS Fiddle but when I click on New/Renew in Chrome of Firefox, the accordion does not appear.  And then I am afraid if it does appear, the hide and show functionality inside won't work.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Here is the Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gullydwarf/zWaLx/11/

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1   /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Permits FAQ</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="new_renew_selection2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new_renew_selection2.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

 </head>

<body>

<br />

<div class="input-quest">What type of transaction would you like?</div>

<div class="input-resp">

<form>

    <input id="question_1_response_newRenew" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

    <label>New/Renew Permit</label>

    <br />

    <input id="question_1_response_transfer" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

    <label>Transfer Permit</label>

</form>

</div>

<div>

<br />

<div class="accordion">

        <h3>Section 1 - Vessel Information</h3>

    <div>

        <p>

            <div>

<h2>Do you own a vessel with a current (not expired) State Registration or Coast Guard   Documentation?</h2>

                <p>

                    <input id="section_1_response_yes" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

                    <label class="labelName">Yes</label>

                </p>

                <div id="section_1_response_click_yes">Please fill out ALL the blocks with your vessel information.</div>

                <br />

                <p>

                    <input id="section_1_response_no" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

                    <label class="labelName">No</label>

                </p>

                <div id="section_1_response_click_no">If you are applying to renew a HMS, commercial swordfish or shark permit issued without a vessel, write "No Vessel" in the field for official USCG Number. All other permits require a vessel.</div>

            </div>

        </p>

    </div>


     <h3>Section 2 - Open Access Permits and Endorsements</h3>


    <div>

<h2>Do you want Open Access Permits or Endorsements?</h2>

        <p>

            <input id="section_2_response_yes" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

            <label class="labelName">Yes</label>

        </p>

        <div id="section_2_response_click_yes">Do you want a lobster tailing permit?

            <div id="section_2_lobster_permit">

                <p>

                    <input id="section_2_lobster_response_yes" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

                    <label class="labelName">Yes</label>

                </p>

             <div id="section_2_lobster_yes">Do you have a current Florida Saltwater Products License with a Crawfish Endorsement?

                  <div id="section_2_lobster_SPL">

                     <p>

                         <input id="section_2_lobster_SPL_yes" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

                         <label class="labelName">Yes</label>

                     </p>

                         <div id="section_2_lobster_SPL_yes">

                             <p>Please provide the Florida Saltwater Product's information in Section 2 and mail a copy of the license with the application.</p>

                         </div>                     

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

        </div>                       

                    <input id="section_2_lobster_permit_response_no" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" />

                    <label class="labelName">No</label>

                </p>

                <br />

                <div id="section_2_permit_reponse_answer_yes">Blah</div>

<h3>Section 4 - Individual Vessel Owner and Lessee Information </h3>

<div>

<p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus    hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>

</div>

<h3>Section 5 - Business Vessel Owner and Lessee Information</h3>

<div>

<p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>

</div>

<h3>Section 6 - Officer Shareholder Information</h3>

<div>

<p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document For New Renew App Help


$(function () {

    $(".accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        animated: 'slide',
        navigation: true,
        active: false,
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.accordion").hide();
    $("div#section_1_response_click_yes").hide();
    $("div#section_1_response_click_no").hide();
    $("div#section_2_response_click_yes").hide();
    $("div#section_2_lobster_yes").hide();
    $("div#section_2_lobster_SPL_yes").hide();
});

$("#question_1_response_newRenew").click(function () {
    $("div.accordion").show();
});

$("#section_1_response_yes").click(function () {
    $("div#section_1_response_click_yes").fadeIn("slow");
    $("div#section_1_response_click_no").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#section_1_response_no").click(function () {
    $("div#section_1_response_click_no").fadeIn("slow");
    $("div#section_1_response_click_yes").fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#section_2_response_yes").click(function () {
    $("div#section_2_response_click_yes").show();
    $("div#section_2_response_click_no").hide();
});

$("#section_2_response_no").click(function () {
    $("div#section_2_response_click_no").show();
    $("div#section_2_response_click_yes").hide();
});

$("#section_2_lobster_response_yes").click(function () {
    $("div#section_2_lobster_yes").show();
    $("div#section_2_lobster_no").hide();
});

$("#section_2_lobster_SPL_yes").click(function () {
    $("div#section_2_lobster_SPL_yes").show();
    $("div#section_2_lobster_SPL_no").hide();
});
```

And here is the CSS, but I don't think it really matters too much.

```
/* CSS Document */

h2 {
background-color:gold;
border-radius:5px 15px;
font-size:1em;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
width:25%;
}



.labelName{
margin-bottom:25px;
color:blue;
}

#accordion{
margin-top:25px;
}

#section_2_response_click_yes{
margin-left:100px;
}

body {
width:772px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the .click() functions into `$(document).ready(function () {` so that they are created when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//...other code
$("#question_1_response_newRenew").click(function () {
    $("div.accordion").show();
});
//remaining functions...

});
```